# Grepping regex from zipped file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, gzip

E.g. having the following file.gz:

```
dbc
1
321
d53 8
```

I can use the following step-by-step approach to grep for regex, show the line number and so on (well, grep is kinda mighty):

```
gunzip file.gz; grep -Pn "^\d{2,}$" file; gzip file
```

Output will be `3:321`.

This will uncompress the file, grep for patterns, compress the file. So I have to have the permission to write data. I don't want to write data and there has to be a smarter way to handle compressed files.

One can easily find [zgrep](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm) which says that options are passed directly to grep. Still, I can't use regex (just [POSIX expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)) with zgrep. I also don't know if zgrep will internally be doing the same like the step-by-step mentioned above.

**So how can I use advanced grep options for compressed files directly, without uncompressing them?**

Comment: Why do you need to use perl regular expression for a so simple task?

Comment: I suppose you have already tried `zegrep` or passing `-E`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The simple task is just an example. I am asking in general how to grep for regex patterns for compressed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do the same using a POSIX pattern:

```
zgrep -n "^[0-9]\{2,\}$" zipzip.gz
```

But if you absolutly want to use a perl regex:

```
zgrep -nP "^\d{2,}$" zipzip.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

`zgrep` is the Right Thing in this case.  If you need to do something similar for other commands that don't have a `zgrep` equivalent, you can generally do something like this:

```
gunzip -c blah.gz | some_command
```

or even more general

```
cat blah.gz | gunzip | some_command
```

This works with any decompressor that inputs and outputs on stdin/stdout (which is most of them).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the -E flag? From the manpage:

-E, --extended-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below).